# Server error caused by file upload

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, server, hosting, error-500

I've got a client who has been trying to upload huge audio files via FTP and then syncing the files in the file manager. The client has found accessing the file manager results in a server 500 error. The web hosts said the server logs reported that 'Script timed out before returning headers: admin.php'. And so the 'software'(ie ExpressionEngine) was the cause.

I'm not convinced, but wondered if there is any setting in EE that can be altered to prevent the timeout.

On a separate issue, the server is located in California, and the client is in the UK. Would that be a cause?

Comment: Are you using filezilla for file upload? Is file completely uploaded on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Assets from Pixel-Tonic? What file-size are we talking about? Maybe your hosting provider isn't providing enough performance?

Comment: How would Assets prevent the server 500 error? Can you explain further?

Comment: Assets isn't using default EE file sync. and might be better. I'm using Assets on multiple sites where we're syncing for example files of 100 mb without problems.